# R: Significance test, two proportions, one sample

Tags: r, statistics, significance, sample-data

I am trying to find out if two proportions from the same sample are different or not.

(let's imagine) I have a sample with 200 answers: 120 like Party A
, 100 like Party B
*It is possible to like two parties at the same time.*

I would like to test whether there is a significance difference in proportion of liking party A or party B.

I see several ways to answer that but none of them seems really satisfying to me:

- Two proportions, two samples test:

```
prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200))
```

This gives: p-value = 0.05619 (there is no difference between liking proportion for party A and B). However this does not take into account the fact that 120 and 100 are not independent.

- Confidence interval for both proportions:

```
prop.test(x = 120, n = 200)
prop.test(x = 100, n = 200)
```

This gives 95% proportion:  [0.5283160, 0.6677775] for liking for Party A and  [0.4313609, 0.5686391] for liking for Party B. These confidence intervals overlap, so there is no difference in liking proportion for party A and B.
However two confidence intervals with 95% confidence does not make a significance test with 95% confidence.

- Confidence interval for the difference:
  There are 20 more people that likes party A than party B in a sample of 200.

```
prop.test(x = 20, n = 200)
```

95% Confidence interval is  [0.06366294 0.15229666], this does not include 0. Party A has a significantly different proportion of liking than Party B.
This tells me that 20 people out of 200 is not 0%, but is it exactly what I want to know?

I am not sure what those three options actually tell me, is there a better way to answer my original question?

Comment: What do you mean include 0? Do you want it to be from a negative to a positive so as to include 0? But prop can never be negative

Comment: If proportion for party A=proportion for party B; the difference between both of them will be 0
In the third method I want to test between the 20 people difference can be considered as 0 (there is no difference in liking for party A and B) or not be considered as 0 (there is a difference in liking for party A and B)

Comment: If you are testing for the difference then you do `prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200))` and check the confidence interval. `prop(20,200)` is not checking for the difference

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I just realized that prop.test(x = 1, n = 200) gives a confidence interval that does not include 0; so this does not test what I wanted it to test; i.e. is the difference in proportion between liking in both party 0 or not.

Isn't
prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200))
testing whether 120 in a sample of 200 is equal to a proportion of 100 in *another* sample? (which is slightly different to my question)

Comment: `prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200), p = 0)`  does exactly that

Comment: prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200), p = 0)

gives me:
Error in prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200), p = 0) : 
  'p' must have the same length as 'x' and 'n'

Comment: Just do `prop.test(x = c(120, 100), n = c(200, 200)) ` That should work. And the confidence interval should contain 0 if it the two are not significantly different